# Remove spaces between two characters with Regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am looking for removing space between two characters at any part of the sentence. For instance, the following phrases:

```
R Z EXCAVATING AND LOGGING
EXCAVATING R Z AND LOGGING
```

should become

```
RZ EXCAVATING AND LOGGING
EXCAVATING RZ AND LOGGING
```

I have tried the following regex `([A-Z](.*?)[A-Z])`, but I have not been able to get rid of the space between the two characters.

Any idea?

Comment: `re.sub(r'([A-Z])\s+(?=[A-Z])', r'\1', text)`?

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, getting `RZEXCAVATINGANDLOGGING`

Comment: `R Z EXCAVATING AND LOGGING` should be transformed to `RZ EXCAVATING AND LOGGING`. The space between R and Z is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
text = re.sub(r'\b([A-Z])\s+(?=[A-Z]\b)', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xcY3qF/3)

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([A-Z])` - Capturing group 1: an uppercase letter
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces...
- `(?=[A-Z]\b)` - immediately followed with an uppercase letter not followed with a word char (letter, digit, `_`).

Comment: OP needs to understand the implication of "word boundary".  This solution may give you unexpected result: `AB-C D EF` will become `AB-CD EF` (as right after `-` is considered to be word boundary too.  Similar for other non word char).  Another possible issue is `AB C D E FG` will become `AB CDE FG` (which means, not necessary to be 2 chars).

Comment: @AdrianShum Word boundaries are context dependant, true. If whitespace boundaries are required, `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)([A-Z])\s+(?=[A-Z](?!\S))', r'\1', text)` can be used. Anyway, OP confirmed the current expression works. If it does not, let OP come back for any further assistance

Comment: Not to criticize your answer but just raising some edge cases that OP may not be aware of.   :)  btw, second alternative works great too, and with a slight twist it could avoid combining more-than-2-single-char, in case OP wants:  `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)([A-Z])\s+([A-Z])(?!\S)', r'\1\2', 'H E L LO YES A B C D E')` => `HE L LO YES AB CD E`

Comment: @AdrianShum This is not a tweak, you erroneously removed the lookahead and the overlapping (consecutive) matches won't be found.

Comment: it is not done erroneously but intentionally: the aim is to allow only 2 single characters to be combined (well, it depends on what is the expected behavior of OP)

Comment: @AdrianShum I would never expect `H E L L O` to turn into `H E L LO`, but into `HELLO`.

Comment: I was expecting `H E L L O` to turn into `HE LL O` by the literal meaning of his question (although I do agree that in real-life, turning into `HELLO` is more reasonable)